# Tkinter: Updating GUI after resizing a window

Tags: resize, window, tkinter

I have a GUI layout that has two dependencies on the screen size: line numbering and tab sizing. When the screen is resized however, I have to manually update `winfo_height()` and `winfo_width()` to change the layout by calling it directly. After searching the interwebs I think I should use `update_idletasks`, but how exactly do you use this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update_idletasks` merely runs any pending ‘idle' tasks, such as screen redraws.

I don't think there is any way to get a notification of when the resolution of the screen changes, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I think I will need to get notification when the window is resized in addition to redrawing the screen. I should have added that this is a text editor and the issue with the tab sizing is this: I wanted to make it so that only four tabs could be open with the traditional gedit, firefox, etc, tab styling. But I wanted the four tabs to be equally spaced so that they each take 1/4 of the screen width. I can currently do this, but like I said every time I change the window size I have to manually call a function to rebuild the tabs correctly.

Comment: Basically yeah I want tabs that will resize automatically (i.e. Google Chrome) when I resize the window.

Comment: You can get notification when the window resizes by binding to the `<Configure>` event of a widget that could get resized. It will fire for other reasons besides resize, too, so you might need to ignore all of them except when you notice the size changes.

Comment: Thanks very much. I can handle the rest, just needed that hint. Simple conditions to test the frame if it has resized with the `<Configure>` event will do the trick just fine.